# How to delete specific text in a column in linux

Tags: linux

I have a file with many lines with 3 columns as shown below:

```
col1    set=SamSNP;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-04-15;Func.ensGene=exonic;Gene.ensGene=ENSCAFG00000000009.3;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-04-15;Func.ensGene=exonic;GeneDetail.ensGene=.;ALLELE_END    GT:PL
```

I would need to delete the text starting from "ANNOVAR_DATE" until the next occurence of "ANNOVAR_DATE" in 3rd column. Desired output looks like below:

```
col1    set=SamSNP;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-04-15;Func.ensGene=exonic;GeneDetail.ensGene=.;ALLELE_END  GT:PL
```

Any solution in linux?

Comment: Linux is an operating system kernel. You wouldn't use it to modify text files directly. What kind of environment are you working in? Do you want a shell script, a C program, use a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this using sed

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(ANNOVAR_DATE=[^;]*;\).*ANNOVAR_DATE=*[^;]*;\(.*\)/\1\2\3/' <filename>
```

This splits the line into 4 parts:

a) All characters until ANNOVAR_DATE,
b) The first instance of ANNOVAR_DATE part,
c) Everything until and including the next instance of ANNOVAR_DATE
d) rest of the line.

'c' is discarded, a, b and d are stored and printed.

`\(.*\)` is stored as `\1`

`\(ANNOVAR_DATE=[^;]*;\)` This part, including the actual date and semi colon is stored as `\2`

`.*ANNOVAR_DATE=*[^;]*;` This selects everything until the next ANNOVAR_DATE part and discards it

Finally, `\(.*\)` stores the rest of the line as `\3`